# Sending a 2d array to the controller from ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am sending name, which is a string, and table data which is a 2d array
And I get the name just fine in th controller, but I can't seem to get the tableData.

This is how I create the table data

**TableData**

```
var tableData = new Array();

$('table tbody tr').each(function () {

    var tableRow = new Array();

    tableRow.push({ 'id: $(this).data('id') });
    tableRow.push({ 'item': $(this).data('item') });


    tableData.push(tableRow);
});
```

**JavaScript**

```
var data = { Name: name, TableData: tableData };
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data
});
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Add(string Name, string[][] TableData)
    {
          // Stuff
    }
```

Comment: What is the data in `tableData`?

Comment: One of the problems is that there is a quotation mark missing in `id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As always in an ASP.NET MVC application you could start by defining a view model that will reflect to your view logic:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Ilist<MyViewModelItem> TableData { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModelItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

then fix the way you are constructing your data on the client:

```
var tableData = [];
$('table tbody tr').each(function () {
    tableData.push({
        id: $(this).data('id'),
        item: $(this).data('item')
    });
});
```

and then the way you are sending this information to the controller (send it as a JSON payload to ensure that complex objects will be properly bound on the server as long as your view model respect the proper format):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify({ name: name, tableData: tableData }),
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

and the last piece of the puzzle - the signature of your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Add(MyViewModel model)
{
    // Stuff
}
```